# Libgdx problems frame rate (FPS)

Tags: libgdx

I am having problems with the frame rate in libgdx, alguin could enlighten me if I'm doing something wrong, because I do not think that is normal, the problem in question is I load a tilemap and simple and if put the highest resolution of 320 x 320, 800 x 600 say this drops to 12 fps or so, I hope to explain well PUE groin is not the native language thanks.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;

private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer bachTileMapRender;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private TiledMap map;

private int[] background = new int[] {0}, foreground = new int[] {1};

@Override
public void create () {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/untitled.tmx");

    bachTileMapRender = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/32f);//Asignar mapa

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 32, 32); //Virtual dimensiones

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //batch.begin();
    //batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    //batch.end();

    camera.update();

    bachTileMapRender.setView(camera);
    bachTileMapRender.render(background);

    System.out.println("fps:"+Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());



}
```

}

320 x 320 the frame rate is about 60 but climbed the window or use the 800 x 600 drops rapidly

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

    config.width = 320;
    config.height = 320;
    new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
}
```

}
P.D: it's worth my computer is a dual core 3000, in debian linux

untitled.tmx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="32" height="32" tilewidth="32"       tileheight="32">
<tileset firstgid="1" name="prueba" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
<image source="title.png" width="384" height="128"/>
</tileset>
<layer name="Capa de Patrones 1" width="32" height="32">
<data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
 eJztwwEJAAAMBKHr8f17rsdQcNVUVVXV1w8ar2wB
</data>
</layer>
</map>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is just dropping when you change the resolution? Could it be the scaling/stretching since 320*320 has a different aspect ratio then 800*600?

Comment: thanks for answering, if I change the class DesktopLauncher config.width = 320; 
config.height = 320; 
for 800 x 600 or higher resolution happens

Comment: Strange, and what if you change it to 800x800? If that still runs good it must have something to do with stretching since you set the camera to 800x800. Also why you set the orthocamera.x to false? You should use camera.setToOrtho(800, 800, false);

Comment: try config.width = 800 and config.height = 800. Then tell me the FPS.

Comment: The same as what? Fast or slow?

Comment: Also the println call is very slow and calling it every frame is not good,probably this slows down the game too ,try printing it every second.

Comment: I thought about doing a graphic font lied but Segua error equal and wanted to make it as simple as possible no where else to look, but it is true that slows println something but do not think the cause

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this?

```
//Swap these lines
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/untitled.tmx"); //first load map
bachTileMapRender = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map); //then use map

camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 600); //X, Y, Z using the aspect ratio you want.

//Gfx config
config.width = 800;
config.height = 600;
```

Also, how many tiles are you rendering?

Comment: My LibGDX :void com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera. setToOrtho(boolean yDown, float viewportWidth, float viewportHeight)  Camera.setToOrtho(boolean ...,Float ...,Float...)

Comment: tiles 31x31 , resolution 32x32 one tiled

Comment: Yes you are right about the orthographic camera, sorry been a while i guess. It must have something to do with stretching since on low resolution you get good results. Not so many tiles either, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Tried testing it without even drawing the map or anything else?

Comment: yes img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg"); frame rate is good 60 simple test

Comment: I have no experience with the build in TMX map loader, i wrote my own parser a while back for more customization. I'm at work now, cant look at your code atm. besides, PM is not possible on the SE network.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, that the problem is the `TextureFilter`.
If the `Texel`s (Pixel of a `Texture`) do not matchthe pixels they use on screen, they need to be recalculated.
For example: You have a `Texture` of 16*16 pixel, which should then use 20*20px on screen.
The `TextureFilter` then defines HOW to calculated the pixel on screen.
There are 2 important `TextureFilter`s:
- `Nearest`: Fetches the nearest `Texel`
- `Linear`: Fetches the 4 nearest `Texel`s

You can see, that the `linear` filter costs much more performance.
So you should try using `Nearest`, which may does not look as good...
You may notice, that you can set 2 `TextureFilter`s:
- Magnification: If the `Texture` is smaller then the place it takes on screen, this filter is used
- Minification: If the `Texture` is bigger then the place it takes on screen, this filter is used.

You can als use `MipMapping`, which gives you the possibility to have different resolutions of the same `Texture`, and the best matching one is used.

I would recommend to read this: [Know Your Texture Filters!](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403)

Comment: thanks for reply, but as I read sometime this article seemed to me interesting but correct me if I'm wrong, the texture which is responsible for charging the charger tilemap is not charged right through textureAtlas and not or do not have access to the type of filter. in the file .pack

Comment: The pack describes the texture filters used. But you should not need nearest filtering to run smoothly on desktop with just a simple tilemap! Maybe you can add the first few lines of your .pack file to your question so we can see how it's set up.

Comment: gracias thanks for reply, I do not use this product .Pack test file was just a question to the previous suggestion, here just loads a map and texture tilemap is charged right through tilemap loader in there .tmx file takes the file path using texture to create tiled I think I

Comment: @AngelAngel so you only load one `Texture`, not a `TextureAtlas`? Then you should be able to set the `TextureFilter` directly to the loaded texture. As Tenfour said, it should not make a great difference on desktops, but its worth a try :)